# Engine for 2.5D Voxel Based City Simulation

Tags: unity, 3d, javascript, unreal, 2.5d

We're looking into making a game where you're part of a city and you're interacting with its economy and people. The world should be an open and procedurally generated sandbox to enable players to the most freedom they can get.

The question we're unable to answer is whether to use a game engine and if yes, which one. We don't have any experience with engines as we're from a web development background.

The style is planned to be similar to Kingdoms and Castles:

- low poly
- voxel based
- more or less 2.5D as in you're looking down on the world

  [image: Kingdoms and Castles]

We have been thinking about Unity and Unreal and are wondering whether those engines are "overkill" or whether they are able to compile down to a result where the unnecessary parts aren't in the game anymore. Also we've been thinking about a HTML5 / JavaScript basis. Obviously, it has immense platform benefits, but we're not sure whether performance would be adequate.

---

**tl;dr** to not get this lost in discussion: What are the benefits and drawbacks of

- the usual 3D game engines like unity and unreal
- a web based approach
- a completely new engine (would the extra effort be justifiable?)

Thanks for any advice

Comment: @Byte56, I've been thinking a lot about whether this would be opinion-based. However, I'm looking for just benefits and drawbacks because I honestly have no idea how those engines work. Would rephrasing the question help? "How much performance would you lose by using an "overkill" game engine for a rather simple 2.5D engine"? I'd be happy to edit

Comment: Too broad that way too. There's no standard performance requirement for game of type X, and engines don't have a rating for that either. There are sooo many variables that go into performance, that it's impossible to say which engine will work best for the game you're *going* to make. All you can do is create a very very simple demo of your game in each engine and test the performance.

Comment: @Byte56 thanks, that helps a lot. I guess we're going to have to write a demo for each option. Thanks for your reply!

Comment: The best thing about that kind of testing is you get to find *which engine you like working with*! Make sure you keep track of how much effort/time it takes to get to the same point in each. I think you'll quickly find something you like. Good luck!

Comment: Personally, I think you'll choose Unity and you won't find it's "overkill" for what you want.

Comment: Unity and Unreal both have their problems. I always start with sustainability. Unity is cheaper for small scale games while Unreal is a % based on profit. Given you team size I'm guessing budget fits more with Unity. Unity is a great engine that runs on 25 platforms. It's easier to learn and has a more saturated community and market. It uses C# as the scripting language and so you don't need to code C++ (Unreal uses C++). I would recommend you go Unity.

Comment: Have said that, Unreal offers source access, allow you to use Blueprint visual scripting to prototype and then covert to C++. You won't have garbage collector issues like Unity and has a lot more performance potential if you know how. Unity doesn't use the latest .Net for its C# and so many features won't be as fast and or even missing compared to real C#. In short, Unreal has much more power but requires much deeper knowledge to tab. It also has less content on market. I would still recommend Unity.

Comment: @ChaoSXDemon 2017.1f2 includes experimental support for C# 6 and .NET 4.6, just FYI.